# Match each of the 4 graphs with its contour diagrams

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, contour-integration

[image]

I need help matching each of the following contour maps with their actual graphs.

I can see that **IV = A**, simply because of the horizontal lines.

Most likely **I = C**, since we can kind of see a hyperbolic nature.

But **II and III** I am not sure about.

The reason is that **B and D "curve upwards"**, and so I am having doubts on which one.

Comment: One of them curves up more at the sides and has more of a pointed minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be B-III, D-II, for the following reasons:

1) B seems "more" convex along the direction going "into" the screen: this matches the fact level curves in III get closer. D seems to tend to a linear growth, matching the fact Level curves in II seem equispaced (approximately of course)

2) if the orientation of the surface and contour plots is unvaried from cases A and C ( the former is unambiguous), more evidence for the B and III match is gained (aspect ratio of the level curves).

Comment: @K Split X, so, what is the solution then?